# Insert with variable number of items - nested foreach

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm not sure how to go about this.  I have a nested foreach that I'm attempting to build an insert query from.

```
preg_match_all('/...../', $text, $matches);
foreach ($foo[0] as $bar){
$item1 = $bar
preg_match_all('/..'/, $bar, $result){
foreach($result[0] as $link){
something here
}
$insertstuff = "insert ignore into table (field1, field1) values (value1, value2)..etc
mysql_query($insertstuff, $con);
}
```

So here is my question.  There will be anywhere from 0 - 10 links returned in the nested foreach.  How do I build the query to take those links and insert them into the respective column, ie link1, link2 --> link10.   This is just a barebones example, I just am not sure how to structure the query to take into account the unknown number of things to insert.

To update:  I have it working but i'm not sure if it's the most efficient.

```
$i=1;
foreach ($result[0] as $link) {
if ($i=1)
{$link1 = $link;}
elseif ($i=2)
{$link2 = $link;}                     
elseif ($i=3)
{$link3 = $link;}
etc down to 10. 
$i++;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: are you trying to have all the links in one field, or does each link have to correspond to a different field?

Comment: I'm sorry. Each link to a different field.

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546842/php-inserting-preg-match-all-array

Comment: I saw that but the use of mysql_real_escape_string worried me a bit. From what I've read it should never be used in production.

Comment: @TheEditor mysql_real_escape_string is used to prevent SQL injection. You could use other php functions to sanitize and / or validate the user input.  For instance you could try using var_filter(). And even create your own rules with Regular Expressions. In any case the principle would be the same, you use preg_match_all to find the links and then insert them in your database. Because this is a barebone project to date I would suggest you try and get your code to work without sanitation and validation rules.

Comment: The question is still too general to fully understand it, unfortunately. For example, do you know what your field names are called? What do $foo and $bar represent? It would be best if you provided a real code example, pointing exactly to what output you need and what isn't working.